# inconsistent respond from data and API using vue.js and axios

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to load data retrieved from my API using axios into vue.js data function.
i've split the process to two functions, one retrieving the data from my api and assigning it to a variable and another one that should manipulate it.

unfortunately when i log the data in each function i get different results.

here is what im doing:

```
let sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('getting');
    const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/leaderboard');
    let resData= res.data
    this.pastWinners = resData.history
    this.chart = resData.chart
    console.log('this ', this.chart)
    this.users = resData.users
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
};

let objectManipulation = () => {
  console.log('manipulating');
  console.log(this.chart)
}

sendGetRequest();
objectManipulation();
```

the first log (from `sendGetRequest`) return the data as it should be:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

whilst the second function returns:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Array
```

thanks!

Comment: Because the `sendGetRequest` is not yet finished when you call `objectManipulation`, the `this.chart` is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@daantje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536590/daantje) answer i was able to fix the problem.

to resolve it i called `sendGetRequest` from within `objectManipulation` using `async` & `await`, like this:

```
let sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('getting');
    const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/leaderboard');
    let resData= res.data
    this.pastWinners = resData.history
    this.chart = resData.chart
    console.log('this ', this.chart)
    this.users = resData.users
    console.log('done')
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
};

let objectManipulation = async () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  let res = await sendGetRequest()
  console.log('manipulating');
  console.log(this.chart)
}

objectManipulation();
```